# Can't read and print pipe content (from child executing through execv)

Tags: c, pipe, execv

I wrote a program that reads a bash file and execute the commands inside that file. I got the execution part working,  but I can't seem to be able to redirect the command output to a pipe, then read from the pipe and print its content. I've read some topics on the subject but the solution do not seem to work. Here is the code,

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

 int pipefd[2];
 char buf[1024];
 int bytes = 0;

 for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // reading file as argument one at a time
   FILE * fp;
   fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
   char * buffer = NULL;
   size_t buf_size = 0;
   char bufread[1024];
   int bytes_read = 0;

   while (getline( & buffer, &buf_size, fp) != EOF) {

       pid_t pid;
       pid = fork();

       pipe(pipefd);

       if (pid == 0) {
         close(pipefd[0]);
         dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
         dup2(pipefd[1], 2);
         close(pfd[1]);

         int length = countWords(buffer);

         char * init_argv[length + 2];
         init_argv[0] = "sh";
         init_argv[1] = "-c";
         init_argv[2] = buffer;
         init_argv[3] = NULL;

         execv("/bin/bash", init_argv);
       } else {

         int status;
         close(pfd[1]);
         waitpid(pid, & status, 0);

         while (read(pfd[0], bufread, sizeof(bufread)) != 0) {
           fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", bufread);
         }
       }

     }
   }
 }

 return 0;

}
```

Why there isn't any output when this program is run with a valid file containing commands as argument? I know without the dup2 and close instructions, the program execute the commands so that is not the problem. As soon as I add the dup2 and close instruction to the program, I can't debug it anymore (it crash at execv).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but shouldn't the call `pipe(pipefd);` be executed before the call to `fork`?

As it is now, I think the parent and the child each create a different pipe, and they cannot use those pipes to communicate with one another, if that is what you want to do.